# Ajax loading Issue Chrome version 37.0.2062.120

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a college project I need to present on monday. It's been working great until I updated my browser.

So I have a site here which allows you to enter search parameters for tweets which then queries twitter and displays charts showing the sentiment.

http://animateoin.com/twitter/

I've checked on older browsers. The content is appended to a div correctly and displays on the page. In the new browser however I get a blank page.

I checked Network traffic and I have jquery.js:9597 pending.

Could this be the cause?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards
Eoin

Comment: Works fine for me in that version of Chrome.

Comment: Try turning off extensions.

Comment: Hi Barmar just tried again. Still no joy. My browser is 37.0.2062.120 m. I'm guessing the m makes a difference?

Comment: I don't know what the m is. I'm on a Mac if it matters.

Comment: i'm windows. Thanks for looking into to it for me all the same